# Example of Navigation between views in React Native Android?

Tags: javascript, react-native

After check the React Native documentation, I still don't understand the best way to create views and navigate between different components.

I don't want to use any external components like:

https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-navbar/

https://github.com/23c/react-native-transparent-bar

https://github.com/superdami/react-native-custom-navigation

I don't need a Navigation bar, i just want to set views and slide left, right o pop a view, nothing more.

I know is something basic, but I can't find any helpful example.

Please, anyone can help me? Any functional example in https://rnplay.org/?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are describing fits the `Navigator` exactly

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**UPDATE 04/2018 :**

Things have change since my first answer, and today two massive libraries are relevant for navigation : react-navigation and react-native-navigation.

I will wrote an example for react-navigation which is an easy to use library and full JS maintain by serious people from the community.

First install the library :

```
yarn add react-navigation
```

or

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

Then in your app entry point (index.js) :

```
import Config from './config';

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(Config.navigation);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('appName', () => AppNavigator);
```

You can see that we pass an object to the StackNavigator, it's all ours screens configuration, here is an example of configuration :

```
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "./SettingsScreen";

const Config = {
      navigation: {
          Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen
          },
          Settings: {
            screen: SettingsScreen,
          }
       }
    }
```

Now the app know each screen we got. We can simply tell the "navigate" function to go to our Setting Screen.
Let's watch our Home Screen :

```
class HomeScene extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
      }

      render () {
        return (
        <View>
            <Button
              title="Go to Settings"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
            />
        </View>

        );
      }
    }
```

As you can see, the navigation will hydrate the props. And from here you can make what you want.

Go to the library documentation to see all you can do : change the header type, the title, navigation type, ...

**PREVIOUS ANSWER :**

Watch this example: 
https://github.com/h87kg/NavigatorDemo

It's useful and a well written Navigator example, better than the one above you just wrote, I think.

Mainly watch the relationship between `LoginPage.js` and `MainPage.js`

Comment: Can tell us addition, how can we pass a dynamic value or object from one page to another?
I tried a no. of examples / solutions but did not found success.

Comment: You can pass some props, in LoginPage.js, watch line 36. However, since the time i answer this question, navigator from React Native has been deprecated. I will update my answer soon, with the new way to do it.

Answer (score 13):

I've found this example:
https://rnplay.org/apps/HPy6UA

And I've written a tutorial about it:
https://playcode.org/navigation-in-react-native/

It's really helpful to understand the Navigation in React Native:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = React;

var SCREEN_WIDTH = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
var BaseConfig = Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;

var CustomLeftToRightGesture = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig.gestures.pop, {
  // Make it snap back really quickly after canceling pop
  snapVelocity: 8,
  // Make it so we can drag anywhere on the screen
  edgeHitWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH,
});

var CustomSceneConfig = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig, {
  // A very tighly wound spring will make this transition fast
  springTension: 100,
  springFriction: 1,
  // Use our custom gesture defined above
  gestures: {
    pop: CustomLeftToRightGesture,
  }
});

var PageOne = React.createClass({
  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({id: 2,});
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Greetings!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go to page two</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
  },
});

var PageTwo = React.createClass({
  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'purple'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>This is page two!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go back</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
  },
});

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.id === 1) {
      return <PageOne navigator={navigator} />
    } else if (route.id === 2) {
      return <PageTwo navigator={navigator} />
    }
  },

  _configureScene(route) {
    return CustomSceneConfig;
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id: 1, }}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        configureScene={this._configureScene} />
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: 'white',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);

module.exports = SampleApp;
```

Comment: Awesome example, tested and works on my android device. Thanks!

Comment: could you let me know, how to finds errors while developing android app. I am using android studio and whenever any error comes it say unexpected token, Its difficult to find out the exact error.

Comment: You can connect your device to your computer and debug using chrome to inspect the console log :D

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) you can take a look to the Navigator Playground [example](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/NavigationPlayground)

- Components built for iOS and Android
- Choose between [TabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab), [DrawerNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer) and [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack).
- Implement your [CustomNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/custom)
- Develop your own [navigation views](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/)
- Share logic between mobile apps, web apps with server rendering.
- [Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/) is pretty straighforward
- It is redux integrated.
- It is super easy!
- Will become the official navigator suggested by react-native!

Install navigation module.

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

Import it in your app

```
import {
  TabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const BasicApp = TabNavigator({
  Main: {screen: MainScreen},
  Setup: {screen: SetupScreen},
});
```

...and navigate

```
class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    label: 'Home',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Setup Tab"
        onPress={() => navigate('Setup')}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please report issue on https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation

Comment: @MohamedHussien Are you in your project directory? Whats is the error you are getting returned?

Comment: So far I have nothing but frustrations with react-navigation, the documentation is not good maybe is your developing simple hello world apps but if you need complex navigation it's really not clear

Comment: I understand that the API has changed since when the project started but the project is great, look at the following example of how you can custom transitions.
https://github.com/narendrashetty/travel-RN