# How can i disable swipe back in react native navigator

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm using react native `navigator` for communication between two screens login and landing screen when i do logout from the landing screen even i can swipe back to landing screen from login screen so how can i disable swipe back in react native navigator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using immediatelyResetRouteStack() will not display any transition. To push a new scene and disallow swipe back have your configureScene return this:

```
return {
  ...CustomNavigatorSceneConfigs.FloatFromRight,
  gestures: {}
};
```

My configureScene function looks like this:

```
configureScene: function(route) {
  if (route.sceneConfig) {
    return route.sceneConfig;
  }
  return {
    ...CustomNavigatorSceneConfigs.FloatFromRight,
    gestures: {}
  };
}
```

Comment: i got fully defined answer from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918666/example-of-navigation-between-views-in-react-native-android)

Comment: awesome. 
but how if, I want to enable swipe in some of scene and disable on another scene?

Answer (score 9):

I assume you have done something like this-

Your navigator looks similar to this-

```
<Navigator 
  style={styles.container} 
  initialRoute={{ name: 'signin', index: 0 }} 
  renderScene={ this.renderScene } 
  configureScene={ () => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight; }}
/>
```

And when you click on "Sign in" button-

`this.props.navigator.push({name: 'componentName'});`

**Instead of `push()` use `immediatelyResetRouteStack()` -**

```
this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{name: 'componentName'}]);
```

This will reset the routeStack and prevent going back to the login screen.

**Similarly, when you log out of your landing screen, use `immediatelyResetRouteStack()` and prevent user to go back to landing screen.**

Comment: This didn't work for me; I had better luck using this.props.navigator.replace({name: 'componentName'}); and navigating from there with a new route. Now if I could keep the transition animations...sigh