# How to start another component in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning `react-native` programming where I have one component in `index.android.js`. I have a `TouchableOpacity` in that component. I want to start next component on click on `TouchableOpacity`.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 10 , backgroundColor: '#2E8B57'}} onPress={}>
    <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>LOGIN</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Can anyone suggest that How can I set click listener in `onPress` and how to start next component on clicking on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by starting the next component? Do you mean like hiding and showing the component?

Comment: This has nothing to do with react native. It's basic OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = React;

var CustomLeftToRightGesture = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig.gestures.pop, {
  snapVelocity: 8,
});

var CustomSceneConfig = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig, {

  springTension: 100,
  springFriction: 1,
  gestures: {
    pop: CustomLeftToRightGesture,
  }
});

var PageOne = React.createClass({
  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({id: 2,});
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Greetings!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go to page two</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
  },
});

var PageTwo = React.createClass({
  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'purple'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>This is page two!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go back</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
  },
});

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.id === 1) {
      return <PageOne navigator={navigator} />
    } else if (route.id === 2) {
      return <PageTwo navigator={navigator} />
    }
  },

  _configureScene(route) {
    return CustomSceneConfig;
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id: 1, }}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        configureScene={this._configureScene} />
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: 'white',
  },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
module.exports = SampleApp;
```

refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918666/example-of-navigation-between-views-in-react-native-android/32920758#32920758)

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional rendering in a single component depending on state/props, so maybe something like this:

```
render() { 
    return state.displayComponent?
    <NewComponent /> :
    <TouchableOpacity ... onPress={() => this.setState({displayComponent: true})} />
}
```

, but if you're looking for something more robust, read up on [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)

Comment: This is a horrible solution. Just make a separate function and call it from `onPress` you want....

Comment: Like I said, this is not a robust solution. He's playing around with react-native for the first time, and has a single component. If it was me playing around, that's what I would do. If you want to build an enterprise-level solution then I would use a router as mentioned, redux reducers+actions, the whole 9 yards...

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of `touchable opacity` is to touch it.

Put your `Business Logic` in a seperate `class` and call it from the Touchable opacity event. Then use that logic in your code where ever you want!

Comment: I have created another file second.android.js now on clicking of `touchable opacity` I want to open second.android.js How can I do what to write in onPress

Comment: @Williams Sorry I am having a hard time understanding what you mean. Can you explain a little more?