# How to create a Hyperlink directing to another page in my React App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hyperlink

I am trying to create a hyperlink in my React app which directs me to another page in my React App i.e WizardFormSecondPage.js

I am only seeing examples of hyperlink which directs me to a particular URL but not to some page already on my app. How do i create a hyperlink which takes me to another page in my React app?

Comment: You need to provide code examples, so that we can properly help you. You should google `react-router` which can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add React Router to get Pages.

The components that you are programming in are just bits of html and javascript without a "page" to them.

Its not too hard, and gives your site a ton of power! Essentially, you assigns a component to a path within the `<Router>` component given by importing React Router.

From there, when you click on a url within your site, React Router assigns the Component that you tell it to the url that you give it.

Here's an example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
  <Route path='/roster' component={Roster}/>
  <Route path='/schedule' component={Schedule}/>
</Switch>
```

The `<Route>` component here assigns  to '/roster' inside your site.

I found this link as just one example, but there are tons of guides to React Router. Good luck!!

https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Answer (score 0):

I think your app need to have some kind of navigation.
follow this link.

[Example of Navigation between views in React Native Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918666/example-of-navigation-between-views-in-react-native-android)

Comment: import { Link } from 'react-router';                                                           
    <Link to={`./WizardFormSecondPage`} activeClassName="active">Second Page</Link>