# Undefined object with RnGestureHandler when using react-native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to implement react-native navigation in an existing app that doesn't (yet) use it.

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918666/example-of-navigation-between-views-in-react-native-android) answer.

Since I already have an app setup, I need to adapt his procedure slightly. My entry point:

```
//index.js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer, createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {Config} from './navigation/config'
import App2 from "./navigation/App2";
import BarCodeReader from "./navigation/BarCodeReader";

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(Config.navigation);

//I've also tried this instead, similar error:
//export const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(Config.navigation);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('appName', ()=>AppNavigator);
```

The AppNavigator .... line is the one that seems to cause the error, according to the red screen of death on my phone when I run it. That's the last line from my code that's mentioned on the red screen of death.

My routing:

```
//config.js
import App2 from './App2'
import BarCodeReader from './BarCodeReader'

export const Config = {
  navigation: {
    App2: {
      screen: App2
    },
    BarCodeReader: {
      screen: BarCodeReader
    }
  }
};
```

My alternative page to load (e.g. app2 - I'm just trying to keep it as simple as possible to isolate the bug and not have my actual code cause unexpected bugs...)

```
//app2.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class App2 extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>          Showing stuff from app2
          </Text>
        </View>);
  }
}
```

When I run it, on the console (webstorm) I get:

```
D/ReactNative( 1044): CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
D/ReactNative( 1044): ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
D/ReactNative( 1044): CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
D/ReactNative( 1044): ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
W/ReactNativeJS( 1044): Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable.js -> node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js
W/ReactNativeJS( 1044): 
W/ReactNativeJS( 1044): Require cycles are allowed, but can result in 

uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
W/ReactNativeJS( 1044): Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/DrawerLayout.js -> node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js
W/ReactNativeJS( 1044): 
W/ReactNativeJS( 1044): Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
E/ReactNativeJS( 1044): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State')
E/ReactNativeJS( 1044): Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

Is this because of the cycle it's talking about? What's the issue with that if so? If not, what's my issue?

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful:

i faced an issue -

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State')
```

the workaround which fixed my issue was **downgrading** the react-navigation version.

in my case i did from `^3.0.4` to `^2.18.0`